# Problem with using 4G Usb dongle

Tags: networking, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I have received a 4G usb dongle and I tried to use it on a ubuntu 18.04 but it is not working

Diagnostic I have done

1. Tried to diagnose with lsusb grep Huawei, the terminal show

   > Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem/Networkcard

   This seem to show that the system recognize it as a modem/nic. Am I right that the problem do not exist in modeswitching?

   I went on to find the partition in Disk but it appear as

[image]

A run of dmesg |  usb, shows

[image]

I wonder is it being connected properly

2. I went on to network connection manager and create a mobile broadband network settings. As I am in Singapore, I uses the default settings of Singtel and the APN as e-ideas

[image]

3. When i tried to use the connection, the systems read

   > Connection failed. Activation of connection failed

   I have to plug in and out again to enable mobile broadband options again
4. The dongle is working perfectly in Windows

Thanks for help!

=====================================================================
Just further update to my problem

when i run nmcli -d in the terminal

[image]

Does this mean the fault lies in my network manager

================================================================
Edit for Shameriff
By running nmcli, it shows disconnected... i wonder why

[image]

=====================================================

i tried to key in usb-devices at cli. the result is

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=02 Cnt=03 Dev#= 12 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=1506 Rev=01.02
S:  Manufacturer=HUAWEI Technology
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=02 Prot=12 Driver=option
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=02 Prot=16 Driver=huawei_cdc_ncm
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

Would this mean my huawei modem is behaving ok

Comment: If you have a hardware issue you should first determine the make and model of the device.  Generally hardware manufacturers offer online support for their products including driver downloads for multiple operating systems. The device may require a driver. If so, it needs a Linux driver and if the device is not widespread or generic, the driver usually must come from the manufacturer

Comment: Can you try to reconnect via dongle after disconnecting the WI-FI, Hope it may solve your problem, as by default the system cannot handle two active internet connections.

Comment: @Shameerariff Nope it still does not connect

Comment: Can you try to provide me the exact error or warning report while connecting via dongle (Make sure nothing connected either Ethernet or Wi-Fi)

Comment: @shameerariff : there is no warning message

Comment: As per the ref (https://apn.global/sg/singtel-apn/) there are no such usernames and password for singtel 4G settings. Can you confirm with your service provider as it seems there is no issue with the OS.